# Creating a dequeue

Tags: java, arrays, queue, deque

I'm trying to create an array-based dequeue but I can't get the order of the output right.
Right now it is bounded but I will probably use unbounded once I figure out how to work the dequeue right.

Here is my code:

```
public class ArrayBndDequeue<T> implements BoundedDequeueInterface<T>
{
  protected final int DEFCAP = 100; // default capacity
  protected T[] queue;              // array that holds queue elements
  protected int numElements = 0;    // number of elements n the queue
  protected int front = 0;          // index of front of queue
  protected int rear;               // index of rear of queue

  public ArrayBndDequeue() 
  {
    queue = (T[]) new Object[DEFCAP];
     rear = DEFCAP - 1;
  }

  public ArrayBndDequeue(int maxSize) 
  {
    queue = (T[]) new Object[maxSize];
     rear = maxSize - 1;
  }

  public void enqueue(T element)
  // Throws QueueOverflowException if this queue is full;
  // otherwise, adds element to the front of this queue.
  {  
    if (isFull())
      throw new DequeueOverflowException("Enqueue attempted on a full queue.");
    else
    {
      front = (front + 1) % queue.length;
      queue[front] = element;
      numElements = numElements + 1;
    }
  }

  public T dequeue()
  // Throws QueueUnderflowException if this queue is empty;
  // otherwise, removes rear element from this queue and returns it.
  {   
    if (isEmpty())
      throw new DequeueUnderflowException("Dequeue attempted on empty queue.");
    else
    {
      T toReturn = queue[rear];
      queue[rear] = null;
      rear = (rear + 1) % queue.length;
      numElements = numElements - 1;
      return toReturn;
    }
  }

  public boolean isEmpty()
  // Returns true if this queue is empty; otherwise, returns false
  {              
    return (numElements == 0);
  }

  public boolean isFull()
  // Returns true if this queue is full; otherwise, returns false.
  {              
    return (numElements == queue.length);
  }
}
```

And this is my main class:

```
public class Dequeue
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;

        BoundedDequeueInterface<String> queue;
        queue = new ArrayBndDequeue<String>(3);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a line of text > ");
            line = userInput.nextLine();
            queue.enqueue(line);
        }

        System.out.println("\nOrder is:\n");

        while (!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            line = queue.dequeue();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, I usually type in:

```
1
2
3
```

And the output comes out as:

```
2
3
1
```

Any help? If you need anymore pieces of my code, just let me know!

Comment: Why you have "rear" and "front"? The "numElements" tells you the position of the rear. Front is always at index = 0

Comment: That part came from the book I was using and it worked fine as a regular queue but not as a dequeue

Answer (score 0):

During enqueue you are at first adding +1 to front, then set the object, but you need to do it the opposite order.

On the other hand it is a very bad idea to implement your own Queue class (unless you do it for learning of course), as Java already has a high-speed, reliable and well tested class for this. You can have a look at the source code of the Java queue class for ideas on how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe stems from the following expression during insertion (equally applies to removal):

```
this.front = (this.front + 1) % this.queue.length;
```

This evalates to:

1. `(0 + 1 % 3) = 1`
2. `(1 + 1 % 3) = 2`
3. `(2 + 1 % 3) = 0`

Because as the third value is stored, due to the size of the queue being 3, you get `3 % 3` which is 0. So the value is stored at index 0.

Have a look at the definition of this algorithm in the [ArrayDeque of the JDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/abc171d85be6/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayDeque.java). They do it like this:

```
public void addFirst(E e) {
    if (e == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    elements[head = (head - 1) & (elements.length - 1)] = e;
    if (head == tail)
        doubleCapacity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant the following (although your overall rational is correct)

Correction

```
(0+1) % 3 = 1
(1+1) % 3 = 2
(2+1) % 3 = 0
```

Instead of your example (since % operator has higher precedence order equivalent to multiplication or division from left to right):

```
(0 + 1 % 3) = 1  => 1
(1 + 1 % 3) = 2  => 2
(2 + 1 % 3) = 0  => 3
```